# sql server equivalent of mysql where in

Tags: mysql, sql-server, where-clause

I have always used a MySQL `Where In` to filter for multiple values of a single field. I am looking for the equivalent for SQL Server. When I set this up on SS it looks at each item as a field in my table instead of a record in my field. Does anyone know the equivalent? Thanks!
MySQL:

```
    SELECT quote_id,entity_id FROM customer.customer_id4
    WHERE
    quote_id IN ("00033658.0","00033361.0","00032971.0")
```

Error when using similar format in SS:

```
    Invalid column name '00033658.0'
    Invalid column name '00033361.0'
    Invalid column name '00032971.0'
```

Comment: `"` is used as object delimiter and not as string delimiter. Solution: `WHERE quote_id IN ('00033658.0', ...`

Comment: If those are strings then you should use single quotes around the values -- `'00033658.0','00033361.0','00032971.0'`. The double quote is interpreting those as column names.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I don't deal as much in Transact-SQL. Fortunately, MySQL is not so touchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"` in SQL server is used to delimit field names. You need to use `'` instead, e.g.

```
... quote_id IN ('00033658.0', '00033361.0', etc...)
                 ^--        ^--- note the different quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to replace double quotes(") with a single quote (').

```
SELECT quote_id,entity_id FROM customer.customer_id4
WHERE
quote_id IN ('00033658.0','00033361.0','00032971.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes in the IN statement and see this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx